# how to access elements in a 2D array in Coldfusion?

Tags: arrays, loops, coldfusion, 2d

I'm running `Coldfusion8` and am struggling to access an array I have set.

My array is set like this:

```
Application.strConfig.respH = arrayNew(2);
Application.strConfig.respH[1][1] = "s";
Application.strConfig.respH[1][2] = 127;
Application.strConfig.respH[2][1] = "m";
Application.strConfig.respH[2][2] = 230;
...
```

resulting in this:

```
RESPH:  
[array]
1) [array]
    1) s 
    2) 127  
2) [array]
    1) m 
    2) 230
```

I need to get the default numbers based on a size I'm getting on a page. So for example, when I end up with `m` I need to get `respH` values for `m`. Right now I'm trying this:

```
 <cfscript>
 LOCAL.runner = "s,m,l,xl"; 
 LOCAL.lt = ListGetAt(LOCAL.runner, LOCAL.i, ",");
 LOCAL.height = Application.strConfig.respH[ LOCAL.lt ];
 </cfscript>
```

Doing so, Coldfusion complains `The value m cannot be converted to a number`.

**Question**:
How do I access the elements in my `strConfig` object?

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: If you need to look up data by a specific key, do not use arrays. Use a structure. With arrays you must loop to find the matching key. (CF9+ supports `ArrayFind`)

Comment: Ya. I'm just changing it to an object like so:  `Application.strConfig.respH.s = 127` to access it like so: `Application.strConfig.respH[LOCAL.lt]`. Let's see if this works. Do you want to make your comment an answer, so I can check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(From comments ...)

If you need to look up data by a specific key, do not use arrays. Use a structure. With 
arrays you must loop to find the matching key. (CF9+ supports `ArrayFind`)